# What is purpose of wavelet scaling function and how is it derived for e.g Haar wavelet or Dabuchies wavelet?

Tags: signal-processing, integral-transforms, wavelets

Scaling function is also called father wavelet. I understand concept of mother wavelet but not father wavelet. In the continuous wavelet transform there is no concept of scaling function but only when we get into multi resolution analysis and subband coding.